# Error message: "Failed to convert parameter from a string to an int32."

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I know this is a common issue, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where the error is. The stored procedure itself works flawlessly, and the code on the client end looks fine.

The parameters for the procedure:

```
@ClientInquiryID int,
@RelatedPartyID int,
@RelatedPartyName varchar(50),
@RelatedPartyPhone varchar(25),
@RelatedPartyAddress varchar(100),
@RelatedPartyCity varchar(50),
@RelatedPartyStateID int,
@RelatedPartyZip varchar(10),   
@RelatedPartyEmail varchar(50),
@IsEmergencyContact bit,
@UserID int
```

The code to fill them:
(They're contained in a Repeater control, and the code is set up to loop through a given list of controls, which is why most of them are using what appears to be dummy values.)

```
repeaterParams(0) = New SqlParameter("@ClientInquiryID", NewID)
repeaterParams(1) = New SqlParameter("@UserID", Convert.ToInt32(hfStaffID.Value.ToString))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyName", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text), txt.Text, ""))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyPhone", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text), txt.Text, ""))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyAddress", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text), txt.Text, ""))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyCity", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text), txt.Text, ""))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyZip", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text), txt.Text, ""))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyEmail", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text), txt.Text, ""))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@RelatedPartyStateID", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl.SelectedValue), CType(ddl.SelectedValue, Integer), 0))
repeaterParams(i) = New SqlParameter("@IsEmergencyContact", IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(chk.Checked), chk.Checked, False))

ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_SQLService.GetConnection, Procedure, repeaterParams)
```

When I insert a breakpoint and look at the values when they're passed to the SqlHelper, everything looks correct. The values of the parameters are correct, and their DBType matches what the variables in the procedure should be. But then it errors out before the stored procedure is even run.

Comment: `@RelatedPartyStateID` looks iffy.  No idea what is in the DDL, but wouldnt SelectedIndex be better than SelectedValue?

Comment: The DDL is populated from a stored procedure pulling from a static table - the text is set to the Name field, while the value is set to the ID. Makes SQL cross-referencing easier.